# How should "off topic" answers be handled?

Tags: discussion, answers

What do I mean by "off topic", well I've always considered an *answer* to be off topic if it simply doesn't answer the posted question (assuming the question is of decent quality).

For example, lets say I've found out `X` about `Y`, but I still need more information about `Y`, so I post a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24200904/2246344) stating the above; several minutes later, there's a couple of [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24201942/2246344) that provide info about `Y` (thus answering the question), but there are also [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24203229/2246344) that *only* talk about `X` rather than actually answering the provided question.

What is the correct way to handle such posts? Should they be downvoted/flagged/ignored?

Comment: They should be down voted, not flagged. If you do flag them a mod will decline the flag. They are *answers*, just not *correct* ones - once they are down voted sufficiently they can be deleted if they haven't been fixed.

Comment: @slugster Right I see; and leave a comment stating why, of course.

Comment: It's essentially just like an answer when they've misunderstood the question. They thought you were asking about X rather than Y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you get answers on your question for the wrong problem your first call to action is to clarify that in your question. You can explicitly state that your question is not about X. But as some users already picked up on X maybe you can re-state your question so X is no longer part of the question only asks about Y, which happens to be what you're after.

Next thing is to inform the users that answered with X that they misunderstood your actual question. In this exchange you might learn why they assumed you needed X to be answered in the first place.

Down vote the answers that are not about Y as they are not useful. Check later if answerers edited their post so you can reconsider your vote.

Flagging the answers is not the way to go. Although they have chosen to base their post on X, they still attempt to answer your question. Not an answer flag will be declined. See the [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) post on MSE from [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) for an in-depth analysis of all kind of forms of Not Answers.